# HTML Button jumps to left side of screen after setting the display

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page with the following code:

```js
let testVar = 0;

function test() {

  if (testVar === 1) {
      document.getElementById("newOrderControl").style.display = "inline-block";
      test = 0;
  }
  else if (testVar === 0) {
      document.getElementById("newOrderControl").style.display = "none";
      testVar = 1;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}

#newOrderControl {
    width: max-content;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  #newOrderInputFields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    row-gap: 5px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    justify-items: end;
  }

  #newOrderInputFields input {
    width: 160px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons {
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons button {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
  }
  
  .btnAll {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .btnAll:active {
    background-color: #1c6ce4;
  }
  
  #btnPlaceOrder {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #btnPlaceOrder:active {
    background-color: #1567e2;
  }
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
    <label class="title">New order</label>
    <div id="newOrderInputFields">
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Action:</label>
        <select id="txtOrderAction">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
            <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
            <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
        <button class="btnAll" onclick="maxQuantity()">All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Target price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Target perc:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Coin:</label>
        <select id="txtOrderCoin">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
        <button class="btnAll" onclick="maxAmount()">All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Limit price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Limit perc:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="newOrderButtons">
        <button id="btnPlaceOrder" onclick="placeOrder()">Place order</button>
    </div>
</div>


<button onClick="test()">Problem</button>
```

The problem is that when I click the first time on the `problem` button, the content is hidden as it should, but when I click again on the `problem` button, the content appears again, but the `Place order` button jumped to the left side of the screen.

How can I keep the button position while hiding and showing the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the display to inline-block on #newOrderControl with your javascript.
Which overrules the inline-flex you have in your css, which  "unsets" your alignment for #newOrderButtons.

Changing this line

```
 document.getElementById("newOrderControl").style.display = "inline-block";
```

to

```
 document.getElementById("newOrderControl").style.display = "inline-flex";
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the css styles for the button. changed it to `align-self:flex-start`

Also to avoid js errors you might wanna set the `test = 0` to an empty function instead

```
  #newOrderButtons {
    align-self: flex-start;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```js
let testVar = 0;

function test() {

  if (testVar === 1) {
      document.getElementById("newOrderControl").style.display = "inline-block";
      test = 0;
  }
  else if (testVar === 0) {
      document.getElementById("newOrderControl").style.display = "none";
      testVar = 1;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}

#newOrderControl {
    width: max-content;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  #newOrderInputFields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    row-gap: 5px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    justify-items: end;
  }

  #newOrderInputFields input {
    width: 160px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons {
    align-self: flex-start;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons button {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
  }
  
  .btnAll {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .btnAll:active {
    background-color: #1c6ce4;
  }
  
  #btnPlaceOrder {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #btnPlaceOrder:active {
    background-color: #1567e2;
  }
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
    <label class="title">New order</label>
    <div id="newOrderInputFields">
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Action:</label>
        <select id="txtOrderAction">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
            <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
            <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
        <button class="btnAll" onclick="maxQuantity()">All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Target price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Target perc:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Coin:</label>
        <select id="txtOrderCoin">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
        <button class="btnAll" onclick="maxAmount()">All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Limit price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
        <label>Limit perc:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="newOrderButtons">
        <button id="btnPlaceOrder" onclick="placeOrder()">Place order</button>
    </div>
</div>


<button onClick="test()">Problem</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting the display of #newOrderBlocks to 'block' and the width to '100%' and the button setting float: right

```css
  #newOrderButtons {
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons button {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    float: right;
  }
```

also in your javascript you may want to change **test = 0** to **testVar = 0**